# Click on Ionic card virtual scroll

Tags: android, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an ionic app.There is a page in the ionic app which contains ionic cards showing corresponding images and text.I also want to implement different click for each ionic cards to navigate to different pages when I click each ionic card.

At this point, I am able to show different ionic cards with different images and text, but I can't implement different (click) for each ionic card.

Below is the code,

category.HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>appname</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="card-background-page">

    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="items">
          <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
              <ion-card collection-repeat="item in items" (click)="item.golink()" class="wallcard">
                  <img  collection-repeat="item in items" class="homecardimage" [src]="item.Url"/>
                  <div collection-repeat="item in items" class="card-title">{{item.Name}}</div>
                </ion-card>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

category.TYPESCRIPT

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,AlertController,LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-category',
  templateUrl: 'category.html',
})
export class CategoryPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private network: Network,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) 
  {}
  items = [
    { id: 0, Name: 'Scruff McGruff' ,Url:'Link1',golink:()=>'goPopular()'},
    { id: 1, Name: 'G.I. Joe',Url:'Link2',golink:()=>'goPopular1()'},
    { id: 2, Name: 'Miss Frizzle',Url:'Link3',golink:()=>'goPopular2()' },
    { id: 3, Name: 'Ash Ketchum',Url:'Link4',golink:()=>'goPopular3()' }
  ];

  goPopular(){
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Please wait...",
        duration: 10
      });
      loader.present();
      this.navCtrl.push('PopularPage');
       }

     goAbstract(){
      let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: "Please wait...",
          duration: 10
        });
        loader.present();
        this.navCtrl.push('AbstractPage');
           }

     goFullscreen(){
      this.navCtrl.push('FullscreenPage');
     }   

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CategoryPage');
    }
}
```

How to implement different (click) collection repeat for each ionic cards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of methods not working ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539768/array-of-methods-not-working-ionic-2)

Comment: @SurajRao I tried according to what is given in the link.Also edited the code according to that.Still not working.When clicked on ionic card,no response.

Comment: dont use string literal here:`{ id: 0, Name: 'Scruff McGruff' ,Url:'Link1',golink:()=>'goPopular()'},` use `()=>goPopular()`

Comment: @SurajRao It's working now.Thanks.